# Permit function and broadcast from another wallet

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

i have script for permit function. And i get valid 'v' 'r' 's' data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3modal@1.9.9/dist/index.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@walletconnect/web3-provider@1.8.0/dist/umd/index.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://bundle.run/buffer@6.0.3"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="main()">click</button>



  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.Buffer = buffer.Buffer // getting this from buffer module for frontend.

    const domainName = "USD Coin" // put your token name 
    const domainVersion = "1" // leave this to "1"
    const chainId = 1 // this is for the chain's ID. value is 1 for remix
    const contractAddress = "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48" // Put the address here from remix

    var account = null;

    const domain = {
      name: domainName,
      version: domainVersion,
      verifyingContract: contractAddress,
      chainId
    }

    const domainType = [
      { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'chainId', type: 'uint256' },
      { name: 'verifyingContract', type: 'address' },
    ]
    
    const connect = async () => {
      // This helps connect webpage to wallet.
      const providerOptions = {
        walletconnect: {
          package: WalletConnectProvider.default, // required
          options: {
            rpc: {
              1: "https://cloudflare-eth.com",
              137: "https://polygon-rpc.com",
              // ...
            },
          }
        }
      };

      const Web3Modal = window.Web3Modal.default;
      const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
        network: "mainnet", // optional
        cacheProvider: false, // optional
        providerOptions, // required
        theme: "dark"
      });

      const provider = await web3Modal.connect();

      window.web3 = new Web3(provider);
      var accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      account = accounts[0];
    }

    const splitSig = (sig) => {
      // splits the signature to r, s, and v values.
      const pureSig = sig.replace("0x", "")

      const r = new Buffer(pureSig.substring(0, 64), 'hex')
      const s = new Buffer(pureSig.substring(64, 128), 'hex')
      const v = new Buffer((parseInt(pureSig.substring(128, 130), 16)).toString());


      return {
        r, s, v
      }
    }

    const signTyped = (dataToSign) => {
      // call this method to sign EIP 712 data
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
          method: "eth_signTypedData_v4",
          params: [account, dataToSign],
          from: account
        }, (err, result) => {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          resolve(result.result)
        })
      })
    }

    async function createPermit(spender, value, nonce, deadline) {
      const permit = { owner: account, spender, value, nonce, deadline }
      const Permit = [
        { name: "owner", type: "address" },
        { name: "spender", type: "address" },
        { name: "value", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "nonce", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "deadline", type: "uint256" },
      ]
      
      const dataToSign = JSON.stringify({
          types: {
              EIP712Domain: domainType,
              Permit: Permit
          },
          domain: domain,
          primaryType: "Permit",
          message: permit
      });

      const signature = await signTyped(dataToSign)
      const split = splitSig(signature)

      return {
        ...split, signature
      }
    }

    async function main() {
      await connect()

      const permit = await createPermit("spender address", 1000, 0, 2661766724)
      console.log(`r: 0x${permit.r.toString('hex')}, s: 0x${permit.s.toString('hex')}, v: ${permit.v}, sig: ${permit.signature}`)
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

After recieveving vrs data i go to etherscan.io USDC contract and connect my spender address
etherscan. io /token/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48#writeProxyContract

Fill the form

[image]

But i have an error in my metamsk

[image]

Whats the problem?
I want to make permit sign on my main account and broadcast permit function from my another account.